# How to support only md and lg screen sizes in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I don't want my pages to adapt on screens below 992px (bootstrap medium size). If the screen gets smaller than this, I just want a horizontal scrollbar to appear.

Edit:
this is what I've tried:

```
body {
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: auto !important;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

it gets a horizontal scrollbar, but still resizes the other divs just like it does.

Comment: Can't you just apply a min-width to the .container and not use any col-xs or col-sm classes?

Comment: Please post your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new rule with media query in your CSS to force the width of bootstrap container:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .container{
        width: 970px;
    }
}
```

You can find more info about [disabling responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) in the official documentation if you need.